# Generate a new column in pandas - conditionaly increase integer count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, conditional-statements, calculated-columns

I would like to have a dataframe of pandas like following:
[Required Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh8Le.png)

Column A - according to these values i would like to generate a new variable - Column B.

All the time, when the values change, it should be "Step_(new_number)" made. So the first zero values are Step_1, then the next values should be Step_2, then other row with numbers should be Step_3 and so on.

This is what i have done so far:

```
def f(row):
    if row['A'] > 0 :
        val = "Step_1"
    else:
        val = "Step_0"
    return val
df['B'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

But i do not understand, how to conditionaly increase the count of the values in the new column B.
Please note that Step_1 could be replaced by "1" - it does not need to be a text, in order to make the solution easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create some global variables to track the value and the step and reference/update those inside the function that you use with `pandas.Series.apply` like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A = [0,0,0,44.67,44.67,0,0,35.49,35.49,35.49,0]
))

step = 0
value = None

def get_step(x):
    global step
    global value
    if x != value:
        value = x
        step += 1
    return f'Step_{step}'

df['B'] = df['A'].apply(get_step)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        A       B
0    0.00  Step_1
1    0.00  Step_1
2    0.00  Step_1
3   44.67  Step_2
4   44.67  Step_2
5    0.00  Step_3
6    0.00  Step_3
7   35.49  Step_4
8   35.49  Step_4
9   35.49  Step_4
10   0.00  Step_5
```

[Example code in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20A%20%3D%20%5B0,0,0,44.67,44.67,0,0,35.49,35.49,35.49,0%5D%0A%29%29%0A%0Astep%20%3D%200%0Avalue%20%3D%20None%0A%0Adef%20get_step%28x%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20global%20step%0A%20%20%20%20global%20value%0A%20%20%20%20if%20x%20!%3D%20value%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%20%3D%20x%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20step%20%2B%3D%201%0A%20%20%20%20return%20f'Step_%7Bstep%7D'%0A%0Adf%5B'B'%5D%20%3D%20df%5B'A'%5D.apply%28get_step%29%0Aprint%28df%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=6&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: Hi Phillyclause89, thank you so much. That was a simplified example. The real CSV files consist of 4000 rows and the number of rows is different all the time. Could you please send me an example, how to load the column A from a csv file instead of listing the values?

Comment: You'll want to read up/google on how to use [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) that will give you a `pandas.DataFrame` of all your csv data. once you have that `df` you should be able to use the logic I have in my answer on what ever columns you want.  It's kinda hard to give you specific code examples for loading your csv file without actually having access to your file.